# Creating + joining multiple pthreads in a loop (C)

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am using a loop to create threads, where the user specifies the number of threads through an argument. The general code is as follows:

```
void* thread_fn(void* arg) {
    int num = *(int*)arg;
    printf("subthread received %d\n", num);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int num_threads = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);

    pthread_t threads[num_threads];
    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thread_fn, &i);
        printf("main thread passed %d\n", i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, I am noticing some errors in the output regarding the value being passed into `thread_fn()`. The output varies, but sometimes it prints stuff like

```bash
main thread passed 0
subthread received 1
main thread passed 1
subthread received 2
subthread received 2
main thread passed 2
```

where subthread is receiving 2 twice and not 0. I believe that this has something to do with an incorrect implementation of `pthread_join` (or I'm just not fully understanding how create/join works). Any help would be appreciated in pointing me in the correct direction!

Comment: This question has been posed many times here, but it’s hard to find a good duplicate.  You are not passing the value stored in `i` to the threads, but instead the address of `i`. The value stored therein changes as the loop advances, thus two threads may see the same value there (in the same storage location).